# System.NullPointerException: Argument 2 cannot be null

Tags: unit-test, exception, null-pointer, dmlexception

I am attempting to handle exceptions within the context of using a custom object that we have to display error messages.  I want to capture any exception or dmlexception messages and use them in the error we are displaying to the user but I only want to handle these if the Exception or DMLException object is not null.

I am getting the following error only when running unit tests:

> System.NullPointerException: Argument 2 cannot be null

Here is the line of code that is generating this error:

```
getErrMsg('CMG_42', null, null);
```

And here is the function I am using to handle the display of the errors from our custom object:

```
public void getErrMsg(string errCode, Exception e, DMLException de){
        system.debug('DEBUG: err msg map size:' + errMsgMap.size());
        system.debug('DEBUG: err msg map --->' + errMsgMap);        

        if (errMsgMap.size() == 0){
            system.debug('DEBUG: err msg map is empty, filling it....');
            errMsgMap = utils.LoadErrorMessages();
        }

        if (e != null){
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,errMsgMap.get(errCode)+e.getMessage()));
        }

        else if (de != null){
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,errMsgMap.get(errCode)+de.getMessage()));
        }

        else{
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,errMsgMap.get(errCode)));
        }
    }
```

I am not sure why the unit testing is giving me this error.

Comment: Have you checked the class and line number the problem happens in? The stack trace will normally show which line/class inside `getErrMsg` is causing the problem.

Comment: @KeithC Yes, I have added the function call that is causing the issue in the question above.

Comment: I would expect the stack trace to have an exact line number.

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that the 2nd param you're sending into a method is null and it is not allowed to be.

Given the code that you're showing, it's most likely the parameters you're sending to create the new page message.

`new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, errMsgMap.get(errCode))`

It looks like `errMsgMap.get(errCode)` is null. Should be pretty easy to confirm this and handle it in your code.

Comment: Hi Mark, yes. This seems to be the issue when testing but when I actually physically test the functionality of the vf page there are no issues and I am seeing the correct errors being displayed.